# Node request add headers

Tags: node.js, request

I want to `pipe()` with [request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
request
 .get(url)
 .pipe(process.stdout)
```

works and prints to console. Now, if I try to add headers as in

```
request
 .get(url)
 .setHeader(headers)
 .pipe(process.stdout)
```

I get `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void'`. If I do it the other way around I get `Property 'setHeader' does not exist on type 'WriteStream...`

Are the combinations of these "inline arguments" limited or am I doing something substantially wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object to the get method with the headers

```
request
 .get({uri: url, headers: headers})
 .pipe(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an `options` argument:

```js
request
 .get(url, {headers: headers})
 .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did not tick your answer because after spending time to inspect the source code to find out who was faster I found the other answer to be 9 seconds faster than yours. The least I can do is to tell you to have a wonderful weekend Mureinik